# How to run my Spring cloud stream using SCDF

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

what is easiest way to run my spring cloud stream application using spring cloud data flow ? My idea is to create custom **source** using kafka binder and **sink** as prebuilt starter ,**file**. I am creating applciation which is pretty basic , similar to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_getting_started). I tried creating executable jar and registering it as source using dataflow shell, that didn't work at all. I am already following this [document](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#creating-your-own-applications).

Comment: Can you share your custom source application? GH link, perhaps?

Comment: Here is my source application https://github.com/Dhpandey/SpringStreamDemo/tree/master/StreamDemoApplication. Please provide some reference guide to start with this scenario.

Comment: I tried to locally run your `StreamDemoApplication` and `StreamDemoSink` - both the applications fail to bootstrap with different errors. We'd highly recommend following the [getting-started](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_getting_started) guide by downloading the stream application with the intended binder from [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/). Only when you're able to run them successfully as standalone Boot applications, we can then register in Spring Cloud Data Flow and use it in the stream definition.

Comment: I was able to run both of them as independent applications though . Anyway i will restart with these guide strictly. Thank you. And one more question, Is there any specific way to register stream definition to spring cloud data flow ?

Comment: Here are my new standalone boot application, running fine independently, https://github.com/Dhpandey/SpringStreamDemo ,  How can we then register them on dataflow, please provide some reference or worked out demo.

Comment: Please review the [app registration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps) docs from the reference guide. All the docs are accessible from the [project site](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/), too. Also, there are some SCDF [samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples) that use the OOTB stream applications. Once you register your apps, you can then use them similarly.

Comment: Thanks Sabby, It was much easier then expected. I was able to register using maven coordinates.

Comment: Glad you could get it up and running! Perhaps you could share your final findings and mark this thread as resolved? Others in the community might find it useful, too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally , I found it easier to register custom streams in spring cloud data flow,

I was able to register using maven coordinates as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps).

**My solution:**

For coordinates that look like

```
 <groupId>com.streamdemo</groupId>
 <artifactId>Streamdemo</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I used  `maven://com.streamdemo:Streamdemo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, and registered to SCDF.
  Actual command looks like :

`dataflow:>app register --name mysource --type source --uri maven://com.streamdemo:Streamdemo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

It worked fine.
[Here](https://github.com/Dhpandey/SpringCloudPack/tree/master/StreamSourceDemo) is my code for Source stream.